# Iterate Clojure vectors

Tags: loops, vector, collections, clojure

I am implementing a Clojure function `(gol [coll])` that receives a vector of vectors of the same size with 1 and 0, iterates it checking the near positions of each index and returns a new board; something like *Conway’s Game of Life*

Input:

```
`(gol [[0 0 0 0 0]
       [0 0 0 0 0]
       [0 1 1 1 0]
       [0 0 0 0 0]
       [0 0 0 0 0]])`
```

Output:

```
`[[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]`
```

How can I iterate the vectors and change the values at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Use `assoc-in`:

```
(assoc-in v [0 0] 1)
```

The above will set the top left value to `1`.

To set many at once you can reduce over `assoc-in`.

```
(def new-values [[[0 0] 1] 
                 [[0 1] 2] 
                 [[0 2] 3]])

(reduce
  (fn [acc ele]
    (apply assoc-in acc ele))
  v
  new-values)

;;=> [[1 2 3 0 0] ...]
```

To go from your input to your output the transform would be:

```
[[[2 1] 0]
 [[2 3] 0]
 [[1 2] 1]
 [[3 2] 1]]
```